Where am I making a mistake in the SEO URL? It doesn't work
php 8.2 version is installed
.htaccess
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteRule ^urun/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)(/?)$ urun.php?urunler=$1 [L]

PHP code
$_GET['urunler'];

the error i got
Warning: Undefined array key "urunler" in D:\xampp\htdocs\dijitalurun\urun.php on line 2
Can you help me? thank you
I changed xampp version, php 8.2 version is installed

Give an example of what URL you are initially requesting.

With such a partial "overlap" between the "fake" path, and the real script filename, MultiViews can often interfere. See if things change, when you add -MultiViews to your options.

Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteRule ^urun/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)(/?)$ urun.php?urunler=$1 [L]
I did this and I still get the same error

I said add to your options, not add an additional Options directive (the second one would overwrite the first), and + and - are also different things.

You solved the problem, I am grateful to you.

It seems like the $_GET['urunler'] is not being set properly in your PHP script. Double-check that the rewrite rule in your .htaccess file is correctly passing the 'urunler' parameter. Also, ensure that mod_rewrite is enabled in your Apache configuration. Additionally, try using isset() or empty() to check if the 'urunler' key is set before accessing it to avoid the warning.
